# Select a random number of records from a table where column value does not repeat for the result set in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, distinct

have a table with a "tag" column - I want to select 10 random records from my table where none of the ten records share the same tag (each record has a unique tag). How would I do this? This is my current query:

```
$this->db->select('extra_imagery');
$this->db->where('cat', '4');
//need something like: $this->db->where('tag',IS UNIQUE);
$this->db->limit($this->config->item('imagery-limit'));
$this->db->order_by('extra_imagery.id','RANDOM');
```

Comment: add `DISTINCT` and/or a `GROUP BY` to your query.

Comment: so just  - `$this->db->distinct()`? Or do I need to specify which column needs to be the distinct one somehow? Seems like there should be an option to say `$this->db->distinct('tag')`

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html - `$this->db->distinct();` - `$this->db->group_by("title");`

Comment: You're welcome. It has been done, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid repeats, you can use `DISTINCT` and/or a `GROUP BY` to your query.

As per what the manual states:

- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

For example:

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

and/or

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

Other references (MySQL):

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT extra_imagery FROM table_name WHERE cat = 4 GROUP BY RAND() id");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```